# No se ejecuta consulta MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

No he podido resolver el siguiente problema, tengo un formulario el cual valido con smoke.js de la siguiente manera:

```html
$('#btn_guardar').click(function () {
    if ($('#form_datos').smkValidate()) {
        var datos = 'nombreUno=' + $('#nombreUno').val() +
            '&nombreDos=' + $('#nombreDos').val() +
            '&apellidoUno=' + $('#apellidoUno').val() +
            '&apellidoDos=' + $('#apellidoDos').val() +
            '&personal=1';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'formulario.php',
            data: datos
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $.smkAlert({
                    text: 'Se actualizaron correctamente los datos',
                    type: 'success',
                });
            } else {
                $.smkAlert({
                    text: 'Se presento un problema intente de nuevo',
                    type: 'danger'
                });
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Con los datos del formulario actualizo una tabla en Mysql y tras actualizar los datos realice una nueva consulta a la base de datos y de nuevo dependiendo del resultado me lleve a una u otra pagina, pero aunque actualiza los datos se salta la consulta y me arroja el smkAlert danger que esta en el script cuando se presenta un problema.

Este es el query que utilizo:

```html
$smtr=$db->prepare('UPDATE persona SET nombreUno=:nombreUno,nombreDos=:nombreUno,apellidoUno=:apellidoUno,apellidoDos=:apellidoDos  WHERE usuario=:usuario');
            
            $smtr->bindValue('nombreUno',$_POST['nombreUno']);
            $smtr->bindValue('nombreDos',$_POST['nombreDos']);
            $smtr->bindValue('apellidoUno',$_POST['apellidoUno']);
            $smtr->bindValue('apellidoDos',$_POST['ApellidoDos']);
            $smtr->bindValue('usuario',$_SESSION['usuario']);
            $smtr->execute();
            
                   
 if($smtr){
   echo 1;
   $consulta=$db->prepare('SELECT estado FROM persona WHERE usuario=:usuario');
   $consulta->bindValue('usuario',$_SESSION['usuario']);
   $consulta->execute();
   $resultado=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if($resultado['estado']==1){

             header('location:index.php');

        }else{
              header('location:formulario.php');
             }
 
  }else{
   echo 0;
  }
```

Lo que sucede es que no se ejecuta el `SELECT`. Que cambios podría implementar?

Comment: no falta un `bindValue`?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @aloMalbarez,  pero me falto al momento de transcribir el código, igual no funciona agregándolo.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo mucha experiencia en PHP, pero creo que hay un error en tu código. Si me equivoco me corriges.

```js
$smtr=$db->prepare('UPDATE persona SET nombreUno=:nombreUno,nombreDos=:nombreUno,apellidoUno=:apellidoUno,apellidoDos=:apellidoDos  WHERE usuario=:usuario');

$smtr->bindValue('nombreUno',$_POST['nombreUno']);

$smtr->bindValue('nombreDos',$_POST['nombreDos']);

$smtr->bindValue('apellidoUno',$_POST['apellidoUno']);

$smtr->bindValue('apellidoDos',$_POST['ApellidoDos']);

$smtr->bindValue('usuario',$_SESSION['usuario']);

$smtr->execute();

if($smtr){
  echo 1;
  $consulta=$db->prepare('SELECT estado FROM persona WHERE usuario=:usuario');

  $consulta->bindValue('usuario',$_SESSION['usuario']);

  $consulta->execute();
  
  // aqui creo que tienes el error:
  // $resultado=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  // creo que deberías ponerlo asi:
  if($consulta) {
    $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($resultado['estado']==1){
      header('location:index.php');
    }else{
      header('location:formulario.php');
    }
  } else {
    // aqui manejas el caso que consulta es 'false'.
  } // fin if(consulta)
   
}else{
  echo 0;
}
```

Espero que esta sea la solución a tu problema, sino ya me comentarás.

Y como dije antes, no tengo mucha experiencia en PHP, me corriges si estoy equivocado.